How to limit methods in class to only overrides
I am implementing Page Object Model for mobile application automation framework. For readability for each page I want to have 2 classes - Page itself having properties and basic functions only and Steps to have all other methods.
I want to create abstract class with some abstract methods and then force all classes that inherit from this class to have implementation only for these needed overridden methods, no more.
I tried to create classes as follows:
abstract class A() {
    abstract fun foo()
    abstract fun bar()
}

final class ImplA(): A() {
    override fun foo() { println("foo") }
    override fun bar() { println("bar") }
    fun baz() { println("baz") } //not wanted
}

Then creating all object of class ImplA() casted directly to abstract class A():
fun main() {
    val tmp = ImplA() as A()
    tmp.foo()
    tmp.bar()
    tmp.baz()
}

In such case I got exception when calling tmp.baz(). I see 2 problems with this solution:

I need to remember to cast every object to abstract class.
Nothing prevents defining other (non overridden) methods in classes.

Is there any other way of preventing defining non overridden methods in classes?

This is not possible. Neither does it seem useful. Can you explain why you even want that in the first place? Perhaps there is another way to achieve what you want.

Sure, I just want to keep the most basic info (properties + 2 methods for navigation and validation) about the page in one Page class, every other, more complex method I want to keep in separated Steps class that will have Page object as property. I just want to force tidiness and forbid definition of any other method in Page class instead of Steps class.

Well, that's not how OOP works, also see broot's answer below. You might want to look up Separation of concerns and polymorphism, especially Subtype polymorphism to learn more about the reasons for that.  The simple solution is: If you don't want anything else in a subclass, then don't put anything in that class. If you are only interested in the members of the superclass, only work with the supertype, ignoring the specific subtype.

In general, another approach might be to avoid subclassing entirely, and instead define a class which takes and stores two lambdas, which you instantiate as needed.  But I agree with the others: it sounds like an odd and probably unnecessary requirement.

This is very unusual thing to do and most probably it is caused by misunderstanding the concept of object-oriented programming. We require implementations to provide specific methods, we don't require not providing anything more. Also, when implementing abstract methods, we often need to introduce more methods.
You can potentially use the reflection API in the A constructor to detect this case and throw an exception - this way you will get at least runtime checks. You can create your own compiler plugin to get compile-time checks. But again, please don't do, it doesn't make too much sense.
